# Configure different FPS for Surfaces using Android Camera2

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-camera2, android-mediacodec

I have two SurfaceView in Android, one for directly rendering the Camera Preview (**surface_A**) and the other is input of MediaCodec (**surface_B**). I have added these Surfaces to Builder and started the Camera Session.

```
mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface_A); // SurfaceView to render the camera Preview directly.
mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface_B); // Surface retrieved from MediaCodec.
```

Is it possible to configure two different FPS for surface_A and surface_B ? Say *surface_A* will render at 30 FPS and MediaCodec *surface_B* will receive Camera Frames at 15 FPS ?

Is it possible using Camera2 API's / MediaCodec ? Else what will be optimal way to achieve this ?

Comment: How about rendering to surface texture at 30 fps and after that you can render it to preview at the same fps while feeding encoder every other frame to achieve 15 fps

Comment: @jfawkes Appreciate your method. That seems to be restricting the frames at Software by our own technique. Is that the only option available for developers(may be something at API level ) ?

Comment: I don't think such API is currently available, taking account that camera hardware will optimize its configuration (shutter speed, iso, etc) for a given frame rate setting, I don't think it can outputs multiple frame rate images at the same time.

Comment: Got your point. Thanking for your reply.